# Export IIS in-process session data while debugging

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I have production IIS server with some ASP.NET MVC app. I got some tricky bug which I can't capture. It's linked to session data. How can I export/see/view such user session? There is default IIS configuration for session storing -- in-process.

---

**EDIT**

By the way I have necessary appropriate user session ID.

---

**EDIT2**

Ok, guys, so even if I can't export that data right now, could you please point me at some session state server or something similar, which I can use for storing session data and view it further? 
I kniw SQL Server can, but it is very heavy for such issue.

Comment: Could you try what I've suggested ?

Comment: @Arno2501 Sorry, this is not what I need. I appreciate your answer anyways.

Comment: oh ok no problem don't understand what you might need though

Comment: @Arno2501 Sorry for my crap english :(

Comment: @kseen : Have you tried any plug-able distributed cache provider for sessions storage ?

Answer (score 3):

Chris is right following on his Idea, you could write a routine that would output the content of your session objects to a file (a kind of a custom log).

```
//Controller Action where you store some objects in session
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myObj = new { strTest = "test string", dtTestValue = DateTime.Now, listTest = new List<string>() { "list item 1", "list item 2", "list item 3"  }};
    Session["test1"] = "Test";
    Session["test2"] = myObj;

    return View();

}

//Controller Action where you output session objects to a file 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    //Routine to write each sessionObject serialized as json to a file 
    foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
    {
        var obj = Session[key];
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\CustomAspNetLog.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\t" + serializer.Serialize(obj));
        } 
    }
    return View();
}
```

If you need to call that routine often, you can put it in some helper class and call it whenever you want in your controller actions. Then you are able to inspect true data inside Session at every step you find necessary.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will need to write a routine to export the session data as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

KSeen

There is a better option to store sessions than a StateServer i.e Distributed Cache provider.

Alachisoft provides NCache Express which is totally free.You can use it to store your sessions.Here is how you do it.

Install NCache on each web server. 
Define a distributed cache: Make sure you test the distributed cache to ensure it is properly working. 
Modify web.config file: to add the SessionState Provider information and the name of the cache you've just created.

```
  <sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
   mode="Custom"
                customProvider="NCacheSessionProvider" timeout="1">
        <providers>
              <add name="NCacheSessionProvider"
                    type="Alachisoft.NCache.Web.SessionState.
                    NSessionStoreProvider"
                    cacheName="myreplicatedcache" 
        writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
                    AsyncSession="false"/>
        </providers>
  </sessionState>
```

Please note that Version=3.2.1.0 should match the specific NCache Express version you've downloaded. Once you do this, you're ASP.NET application is ready to start using distributed sessions.